# Razor - declaring and calling a variable inside foreach loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am relatively new to razor, so there is probably a lot wrong with this code, but I cannot get it to work. I am trying the grab the full path of a file, and get a loop of all files in that specific folders, and to output the name of the files in a list

First I declare a variable with the full path to a file like this: folder/folder/filename.jpg

Then I try to get the substring to this like folder/folder

Last I try to loop through the files in the folder, and output the full path to the files.

My code is

```
@foreach (LoopItem i in GetLoop("Products")){


    string input = i.GetValue("Ecom:Product:Field.Images.Clean");
    string folder = input.Substring(0, input.LastIndexOf("/"));


   foreach(var file in GetLoop(folder.ListOfFiles)){

     GetValue(folder)/file.GetValue(folder.FileName);

   }
}
```

Error message I get is:

> Line 28: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
>   Line 32: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'ListOfFiles' and no extension method 'ListOfFiles' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: The error is saying you have declared `string folder =` but String does not have an instance method `.ListOfFiles()`. Is that a custom extension?

Comment: I am afraid i don´t know. Is ListOfFiles() a standard Razor function that loops through the files of a folder? the variable "folder" is just the path to the folder, so it doesn´t have to be string if it can be something else.

Comment: If you don't know, where did you get the idea to call `ListOfFiles`? The problem with what you are trying to do is expecting a string method to give you a list of objects i.e. `"myFolderName".ListOfFiles`.

Comment: See here on how to get [file system info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yk7a1b0.aspx). But since this is a web app you are likely to get Windows permission errors. Also keep in mind which file system you are trying to access: server or client. You will not be able to access the clients' file system.

Comment: You might find it easier to take all of that logic out of the view and move it to the server side. Create a ViewModel with a single property, which is the list of file paths you want to display. It's a trivial task to display a list of strings and your more complex logic is within the controller (or a factory or some such that initialises your ViewModel). If you've got a lot of  complex logic within your views, they're much harder to test and maintain